# Where does the idea that French people say "oh la la" all the time come from ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, culture

As a French man living abroad, I often hear non-French people saying "Oh la la !" (along with an imitation of a kind of posh attitude) after someone talked about something that is typical of France or French people. I have been told that this expression is supposed to be typical of what French people say, which according to my experience is not really the case ([this blog article](https://davidplusworld.com/french-ooh-la-la/) is going in that direction as well).

Have there been specific elements of French movies, books or any exported culture trivia that made English-speaking people think that "oh la la" is something that French people actually say all the time, or that would explain why this phrase became a stereotype of the French language ?

Comment: I wasn't aware that was considered a typical French expression, but a waiter in Liège (?) saying "oh la la, monsieur" in response to something my father did may very well be the first French phrase I consciously remember hearing. It wouldn't surprise me if foreigners shock speakers of French more frequently than natives, with the potential for increased utterances of "oh la la". But I mean that as in surprise, not as in some kind of posh attitude.

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4513/what-does-the-expression-oh-l%c3%a0-l%c3%a0-mean. But I would sooner look into English-language movies or books to find an explanation, if any.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: football (soccer) highlights of goals/etc. with french commentators often include occurences of "oh la la" and variations of it ("Oh la la quel but !", "Oh la la la la ce geste que vient de faire Messi…"). Non-french speakers very often jokingly comment on such uses of "oh la la" (you can find many examples on the soccer sub of Reddit).

Comment: Someone is deleting my posts.This is not really a French language question at all....

Comment: @Lambie Sorry if I posted in the wrong site. I thought that the use of French expressions would fit here, what site do you think would be better?

Comment: @BrunoPérel Probably, the English language and usage forum. I am not by the way criticizing you. :)

Answer (score 10):

French people **do** say *oh là là*, *hou là là* and *houlà* quite often but it doesn't have the connotations found in English. Well, it can but rarely.

Here are examples of its use in French:

> Il est déjà sept heures. Hou là là, je vais rater mon train !
>
> [Houlala le train, il  est en train de partir !](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNj4vxJlOlI)
>
> Oh là là, elle a repris du gateau !
>
> Hou là là, il a dû se faire mal en tombant !

A reason explaining the popularity and oriented meaning of this expression in English might be [Fifi D'Orsay](https://www.theharrison-press.com/opinion/fabulous-french-movie-star-visits-dog-track), actress and singer born in Montreal who made all her career in the US and who made *hoo-la-la* her trademark according to several sources.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, French people do say "ouh la la" but not with this connotation, that's what I wanted to say but didn't phrase it properly. Thanks for the reference, that's definitely a good lead

Comment: I think it is funny that in movies and in the US - people say “Ooh la la” when the expression is really “Oh la la”. I hear it all the time by French people in France, so do not think it is rare.

Comment: @kjstinson I don't believe there is a strong difference between *oh la la* and *hou la la*. The tone used when saying it is far more important than which word is used to make clear what is intended to say.

Comment: Missing circonflexe: *il a dû*

Comment: @Step Corrigé, merci!

Comment: Moi je dis aïe aïe aïe ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I got the idea from Agatha Christie's books featuring a character of belgian origin by the name  Hercule Poirot who often inserted French words into his otherwise English dialogue, such as 'alors', 'monsieur/madame/madmoseille' and also 'Oh, la, la':

> "My dear Poirot! What on earth is the good of that, now that we know
>   about the coco?" "Oh, là là! That miserable coco!" cried Poirot
>   flippantly. ~Agatha Christie - The Mysterious Affair at Styles

While I realized that Poirot with his enormous moustache and mannerisms was a caricature of a Frenchman,  I still remember this phase as a french expression.

Comment: Uh, no. Poirot was a caricature of a Belgian, not a Frenchman.

Comment: @Drew thing is, he was seen as french by the engish characters in the various books. One even responds to poirot's 'i am Belgian,  not French' with 'Belgian,  French... what's the difference"

Comment: @Morrigan Would you define Sean Connery as an Englishman?

Comment: @jlliagre [That guy is so awesome that he becomes whatever he plays](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/SugarWiki/RuleOfSeanConnery). guys, relax, poirot was intended to be a parody of frenchman/belgians by the author, it's not an insult towards them... and it was a joke :-)

Comment: You might be confusing *Hercule Poirot* with *[Achille Aubergine](http://www.jamesbondmm.co.uk/bond-allies/jean-rougerie)* ;-)